# 8 Puzzle: Sorting STL Heap/Priorirty Queue containing pointers to object by member variable

Tags: c++, stl, sliding-tile-puzzle

I'm working on implementing a Best-First Search algorithm to solve an 8-Puzzle problem for an assignment. Based on the requirements, it must be implemented using a **(min) Priority Queue or Heap** located in the **Standard Template Library (STL)**.

I understand that it would be useful to use either data structure to organise expanded puzzle states by best heuristic cost (ie. the smallest cost).

---

Beginning with a 3x3 matrix (implemented using an array)

```
Puzzle *current=new Puzzle(initialState, goalState);
```

Each new puzzle state (an object) is created using:

```
Puzzle *next=(current->moveDown());
Puzzle *next=(current->moveRight());
Puzzle *next=(current->moveUp());
Puzzle *next=(current->moveRight());
```

I'd like to `.push(next)` onto a (Min) Priority Queue or Heap (of `Puzzle*`), sorted according to `next->FCost`.

---

Generically, is there a way that I can use either of these STL data structures to contain pointers to objects - sorted by a member variable (FCost) specific to each object?

Comment: You can use a custom ordering function with `priority_queue`. (You can do that with all ordered collections.)

Comment: Unrelated, but I don't see why current needs to be allocated dynamically. See [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (or better named, end-scope does cleanup)](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#e6-use-raii-to-prevent-leaks). I'd recommend simply `Puzzle current(initial, goal)`. Notwithstanding of course your other variables may point into that stack variable, e.g. `Puzzle *next = current.moveDown();`

Comment: The rule of thumb is, don't ever write `new` without wrapping it immediately into a resource-handling class, such as `std::unique_pointer current = std::make_unique(new Puzzle(initial, goal));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can specify a custom compare function for [priority_queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

```
auto cmp = [](Puzzle* a, Puzzle* b) { 
    return a->FCost > b->FCost;
};

std::priority_queue<Puzzle*, std::vector<Puzzle*>, decltype(cmp)> queue(cmp);
```